# Android check if string contains number before a word

Tags: java, android

I am currently using an arraylist to store some text and then later checking that list to see if it contains certain words and parsing them for the numbers. For example my arraylist could contain:

```
[cancel, port, 4.5, 3 min, 3/4 terminal]
```

And I want to parse the `3 min` to get the number `3`. I currently use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textArray.size(); i++) {
  if (textList.contains("min")
     number = Double.parseDouble(textList.get(i).replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
}
```

But the issue I am having is that it will see the `3 min` and it will also see the `3/4 terminal` because it contains `min`. Is there a way to use contains to make sure the word is exactly `min`?

Comment: Try this space before min (textList.contains(" min"))

Comment: @AnasMehar that might be good unless something like minimal shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `contains()` use `endsWith()`:

```
if (textList.endsWith(" min") {
    number = Double.parseDouble(textList.get(i).replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if the string starts with a number and then checking if that string has an exact match for the word min?

```
    String[] strValues = {
        "cancel",
        "port",
        "4.5",
        "3 min",
        "3/4 terminal"
    };

    for(String str : strValues){

        if(str.matches("^[0-9].*$"))
            System.out.println(str + " starts with a number");
            String[] results = str.split("\\s+");
            Boolean matchFound = Arrays.asList(results).contains("min");
            System.out.println(str + " is a number that contains a the word min");
        else
            System.out.println(str + " does not start with a number");

    }
```

Code is untested but it should give you what you asked for which was to use contains.
There are better ways though as others have answered